Retrieving Username property from Get-Service commands on remote servers thru Powershell 7
In PowerShell 7.0, if I run Get-Service | Select Name, Username | ft I get results like:
Name                                      UserName
----                                      --------
AarSvc_42bd40
AbtCdcSvc                                 LocalSystem
AbtSngSvc                                 LocalSystem
AdobeARMservice                           LocalSystem
AdobeUpdateService                        LocalSystem

Unfortunately Get-Service stopped including the -ComputerName property starting with PowerShell 6.0; I'm trying to run the same command remotely in PowerShell 7.0, but it's "acting funny".

If I run the same command remotely:
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'remoteServerName' -ScriptBlock { Get-Service | Select Name, UserName | ft }
I get empty Usernames:
Name                                     UserName
----                                     --------
AJRouter
ALG
AppHostSvc
AppIDSvc
Appinfo

Does anyone know why the UserName is missing?

What is the server Powershell version? UserName added to the result starting from Powershell 6.0

Try running Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service | Select-Object -Property Name, startName

The remote is running 5.1.

PowerShell (Core) 7 versions target Windows PowerShell in remoting operations by default; targeting PowerShell 7 on the remote machine too  - assuming it is installed and remoting has been enabled for it - requires explicit opt-in.
See the linked duplicate for details.

If the remote target machine doesn't have PowerShell 7 installed or doesn't have remoting enabled for it: see user459872's answer for a solution that works in Windows PowerShell too.

This is because your server is running with Powershell version < 6.0. UserName added to the Get-Service cmdlet result starting from Powershell 6.
Quoting from the documentation:

Beginning in PowerShell 6.0, the following properties are added to
the ServiceController objects: UserName, Description,
DelayedAutoStart, BinaryPathName, and StartupType .

You can use the Get-CimInstance Cmdlet to query the Win32_Service class in order to get the same result in older versions.
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service | Select-Object -Property Name, startName


THANK YOU to everyone's explanations and workarounds; Get-CimInstance alternative helped me continue my existing code block with -Computername and now I know I'm targeting Windows Powershell by default, I can look at targeting Powershell 7 on the remote computer, too!
